# Total Count of Active Employees by Date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have in the past written queries that give me counts by date (hires, terminations, etc...) as follows:

```
SELECT per.date_start AS "Date",
  COUNT(peo.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER) AS "Hires"

FROM hr.per_all_people_f peo,
  hr.per_periods_of_service per

WHERE per.date_start BETWEEN peo.effective_start_date AND peo.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE

AND per.date_start BETWEEN :PerStart AND :PerEnd

AND per.person_id = peo.person_id

GROUP BY per.date_start
```

I was now looking to create a count of active employees by date, however I am not sure how I would date the query as I use a range to determine active as such:

```
SELECT COUNT(peo.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER) AS "CT"

FROM hr.per_all_people_f peo

WHERE peo.current_employee_flag = 'Y'

and TRUNC(sysdate) BETWEEN peo.effective_start_date AND peo.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
```

Comment: What (if anything) seems to be wrong with your query?

Comment: You need a list of dates to test?  Will current_employee_flag be changed when you cross over an start/end date?  (If you're looking back at employees you had last month, will the current current_employee_flag be incorrect for those just hired/fired?

Comment: His first query is something of a pivot table, I'm guessing he wants the same for the second query, but there's no relevant dates to use in his data set, he only has a count of active people today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way to get started. This works for all the effective and end dates in your data:

```
select thedate,
       SUM(num) over (order by thedate) as numActives
from ((select effective_start_date as thedate, 1 as num from hr.per_periods_of_service) union all
      (select effective_end_date as thedate, -1 as num from hr.per_periods_of_service)
     ) dates
```

It works by adding one person for each start and subtracting one for each end (via `num`) and doing a cumulative sum.  This might have duplicates dates, so you might also do an aggregation to eliminate those duplicates:

```
select thedate, max(numActives)
from (select thedate,
             SUM(num) over (order by thedate) as numActives
      from ((select effective_start_date as thedate, 1 as num from hr.per_periods_of_service) union all
            (select effective_end_date as thedate, -1 as num from hr.per_periods_of_service)
           ) dates
     ) t
group by thedate;
```

If you really want all dates, then it is best to start with a calendar table, and use a simple variation on your original query:

```
select c.thedate, count(*) as NumActives
from calendar c left outer join
     hr.per_periods_of_service pos
     on c.thedate between pos.effective_start_date and pos.effective_end_date
group by c.thedate;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count all employees who were active during the entire input date range

```
SELECT COUNT(peo.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER) AS "CT"
FROM hr.per_all_people_f peo
WHERE peo.[EFFECTIVE_START_DATE] <= :StartDate   
AND  (peo.[EFFECTIVE_END_DATE] IS NULL OR peo.[EFFECTIVE_END_DATE] >= :EndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example based on [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) answer
with a little modification, because in SUBSTRACT table all records were appeared with -1 in NUM, even if no date was in END DATE = NULL.

```
use AdventureWorksDW2012  --using in MS SSMS for choosing DATABASE to work with
                          -- and may be not work in other platforms

select
    t.thedate
    ,max(t.numActives) AS "Total Active Employees"
from (
        select
            dates.thedate
            ,SUM(dates.num) over (order by dates.thedate) as numActives
        from
            (
                (
                select
                    StartDate as thedate
                    ,1 as num
                from DimEmployee
                )
                    union all
                        (
                        select
                            EndDate as thedate
                            ,-1 as num
                        from DimEmployee
                        where EndDate IS NOT NULL
                        )
            ) AS dates
     ) AS t
group by thedate
ORDER BY thedate
```

worked for me, hope it will help somebody

Comment: That is invalid SQL syntax (standard SQL as well as Oracle)

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, why? can you explain please? because it works on MS SQL, and if there a mistake, please show me. thanks in advance.

Comment: In SQL, the `[` and `]` are not allowed as part of an identifier (and `use` is completely non-standard)

Comment: thanks for an explanation. but [ and ] are automatically added while dragging a column to query on MS SQL, and maybe it will not work in some other server type, like maybe Oracle, but I don't think that it's "not allowed in SQL", [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) <<Alias Example for Table Columns
...Tip: It requires double quotation marks or square brackets if the column name contains spaces.>> * I've used "USE" to explain in my answer what database was used.am i wrong?

Comment: w3schools is known to have loads of errors. And your link is a good example for that - that quote is plain wrong (it might be true for SQL Server's T-SQL, but not for standard SQL) The only way in (standard) SQL to use special characters or keywords in an identifier is to use double quotes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109517/discussion-between-spon4ik-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the results I was looking for with the following:

```
--Active Team Members by Date
SELECT "a_date",
  COUNT(peo.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER) AS "CT"
FROM hr.per_all_people_f peo,
  (SELECT DATE '2012-04-01'-1 + LEVEL AS "a_date"
  FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= DATE '2012-04-30'+2 - DATE '2012-04-01'-1
  )
WHERE peo.current_employee_flag = 'Y'
AND "a_date" BETWEEN peo.effective_start_date AND peo.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
GROUP BY "a_date"
ORDER BY "a_date"
```